# java:Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a dynamic template mapping for the index and is continuously receiving the following error:

> ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [doc : {properties={price={type=float}, studymodel={type=keyword}, name={search_analyzer=ik_smart, analyzer=ik_max_word, type=text}, description={search_analyzer=ik_smart, analyzer=ik_max_word, type=text}}}]]
> ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [doc : {properties={price={type=float}, studymodel={type=keyword}, name={search_analyzer=ik_smart, analyzer=ik_max_word, type=text}, description={search_analyzer=ik_smart, analyzer=ik_max_word, type=text}}}]]];

Here is the code that I'm trying to create a mapping with:

```
CreateIndexRequest createIndexRequest = new CreateIndexRequest("xc_course");
    createIndexRequest.settings(Settings.builder().put("number_of_shards",1)
            .put("number_of_replicas",0));

    createIndexRequest.mapping("doc"," {\n" +
            " \t\"properties\": {\n" +
            "           \"name\": {\n" +
            "              \"type\": \"text\",\n" +
            "              \"analyzer\":\"ik_max_word\",\n" +
            "              \"search_analyzer\":\"ik_smart\"\n" +
            "           },\n" +
            "           \"description\": {\n" +
            "              \"type\": \"text\",\n" +
            "              \"analyzer\":\"ik_max_word\",\n" +
            "              \"search_analyzer\":\"ik_smart\"\n" +
            "           },\n" +
            "           \"studymodel\": {\n" +
            "              \"type\": \"keyword\"\n" +
            "           },\n" +
            "           \"price\": {\n" +
            "              \"type\": \"float\"\n" +
            "           }\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "}", XContentType.JSON);
    
    IndicesClient indices = client.indices();  
    CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = indices.create(createIndexRequest); 
    boolean acknowledged = createIndexResponse.isAcknowledged();
    System.out.println(acknowledged);
```

It is a mistake in the mapping code? or everything is ok here and I should take a look at the way of parsing the mapping object?

Comment: Try replacing `"doc"` by `"_doc"`

Comment: I have tried it,but it is useless.